# extracting 1st PHP code block from a text string known to start with <?php

Tags: php, regex, parsing, tokenize

Suppose I have a block of text that I'm sure begins with `<?php`, how could I extract the 1st php code block from the original text?

example text:

```
<?php

echo "uh oh... \"; ?> in a \"; // string...  ?>";
echo 'uh oh... \\\'; ?> in a /* string ?> */...';

// ?> nope not done

/*

?> still not done

*/

echo "this should be echoed too";

?>

this is even more text...
```

I think I would need to use the PHP core function `token_get_all` but I don't see how I can use that to get the size of the PHP block to remove from the original string.  that function obviously knows when it's reached the end of a PHP block.  I can't just pass all of the text to PHP because this is deep in many other layers of processing.

so, the end result should leave me with the string outside the end of the PHP block containing this: (with any preceding whitespace)

```
this is even more text...
```

and the parsed out PHP code in a different string:

```
<?php

echo "uh oh... \"; ?> in a string...";
echo 'uh oh... \\\'; ?> in a string...';

// ?> nope not done

/*

?> still not done

*/

echo "this should be echoed too";

?>
```

Comment: Do you really mean to “parse” out the block? It seems to me you're asking how to remove the block from the text, rather than parse it.

Comment: well, yes, the block will eventually be parsed, but my problem is basically in extracting the block.  i'll change the title.

Comment: How important is it to have the comments in the 'extracted' code? If it's not, you can fairly easily strip them and extract the php with a bit of regex.

Comment: Good to know: it doesn't look like `// ?>` actually comments out the closing tag, it still ends the code block, at least in 5.4. If that observation is right, the regex solution won't need to look for it.

Comment: it's not important at all to preserve the comments... could you provide the code to strip comments and the bit of regex?

Comment: and it does look like // ?> will close the PHP block... not sure if that is intended behavior

Comment: @phil-lavin I'm not sure that's entirely true: comments that occur within strings won't be treated as comments, so stripping them out is a bad idea. I'm not aware that regexes can adequately handle the problem of detecting whether or not a given match is occurring in a string.

Comment: Well, [`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/token_get_all) to the rescue. Just loop from `T_OPEN_TAG` to the first `T_CLOSE_TAG`. Don't try to find it in the original, just build the first block from the output, and the second one as well.

Comment: i need the raw code from the original string... or at the very least i still need to extract out the text that is outside of the PHP block.  i don't see any of that in token_get_all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<?php
$code = <<<'PHP'
<?php

echo "uh oh... ?> in a string...";
echo 'uh oh... ?> in a string...';

// ?> nope not done

/*

?> still not done

*/

echo "this should be echoed too";

?>

this is even more text...
PHP;

function findPHPBlockEnd($code_text) {
    $tokens = token_get_all($code_text);

    $current_character = 0;
    foreach ($tokens as $current_token) {
        $current_character += is_string($current_token)
                            ? strlen($current_token)
                            : strlen($current_token[1]);

        if (is_array($current_token) && $current_token[0] === T_CLOSE_TAG) {
            // End of block.
            break;
        }
    }

    return $current_character;
}

$end = findPHPBlockEnd($code);
$code_block = substr($code, 0, $end);
var_dump($code_block);
```

This outputs:

```
string(83) "<?php

echo "uh oh... ?> in a string...";
echo 'uh oh... ?> in a string...';

// ?>"
```

(Closing tags do indeed work in comments, so this is expected behavior.)

If you evaluate `$code[$end]`, you'll get the character *immediately after* the `?>`, but this is the preferred behavior for `substr`.